# Тисс или тис?

Tags: орфография

Я биолог, и в университете нас учили, что дерево называется "тиСС ягодный" - через удвоенное С. Теперь же я часто встречаю в литературе "тис" через одно С. Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лингвистические словари дают написание "ТИС, тисовый" - и толковые, и орфографические. В специальной литературе встречаются оба написания.